# Implementing Excel Solver in R

Tags: r, solver, portfolio, r-portfolioanalytics

I am trying to implement an Excel Solver in R.

I have two vectors of weights. Old_Weights and New_Weights. I need to find New_Weights.

Objective Function: Max ( (Returns - Cost) / Risk)

Example:

```
Old_Weights<-c(0.5,0.5,0)
New_Weights<-c(X,Y,Z)

Returns <- New_Weights * Market_Returns
Cost<- (New_Weights - Old_Weights) * 15
Risk <- t(New_Weights) * Var(Market_Returns) * New_Weights
```

So basically I need a function that would change the values of X,Y,Z that maximizes the Objective Function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use The `optim()` function in R to compute this.

The general format for the `optim()` function is `optim(objective, constraints, bounds = NULL, types= NULL, maximum = FALSE)`

You can first write a function including your parameters, for example,

```
> f <- function(x) 15 * (x[1]-0.5) + 7 * (x[2]-3)^2 + 30
```

Setting up the constraints next

`> c <- c(1, 1)`

Then use optim(c, f) to get the optimized solution

`> r <- optim(c, f)`

`> r`

Comment: My `?optim` gives a very different description: `optim(par, fn, gr = NULL, ...`.